# How to create a list of dates using a From and To date in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, calendar

I have to create a service schedule, for the next calendar year, for all of our equipment. The calendar year starts from the date the report is run, and goes upto 12 months after that date - so each item will have the same service year. I know the next service date for an item of equipment, along with the service frequency (ie every 12 months, every 3 weeks, etc). From that, I would have to create the service schedule for the next 12 months for each item.

See below example for your reference:

```
set dateformat dmy
create table #Temp
(
  Itemid nvarchar(6), 
  Linenum nVarchar(2), 
  Engineerid nvarchar (4), 
  Nextduedate DateTime, 
  Frequencytype nvarchar (6),
  Frequencyvalue nvarchar (4)
)
insert into #Temp 
Values ('325301','1','Eng1','15/11/2018','Months','3'),
       ('325301','2','Eng2','03/12/2018','Months','6'),
       ('325302','1','Eng3','04/11/2018','Weeks','7')

select *
from #Temp

drop table #Temp
```

What I want to return for the above, is the below records:

```
  ItemID  Linenum  Engineerid  Servicedate
  325301  1        Eng1        15/11/2018
  325301  1        Eng1        15/02/2019
  325301  1        Eng1        15/05/2019
  325301  1        Eng1        15/08/2019
  325301  2        Eng2        03/12/2018
  325301  2        Eng2        03/06/2019
  325302  1        Eng3        04/11/2018
  325302  1        Eng3        23/12/2018
  325302  1        Eng3        10/02/2019
  325302  1        Eng3        31/03/2019
  325302  1        Eng3        19/05/2019
  325302  1        Eng3        07/07/2019
  325302  1        Eng3        25/08/2019
  325302  1        Eng3        13/10/2019
```

Frequencytype and Frequencyvalue indicate how often each item is serviced. So If Frequencytype is 'Months' and Frequencyvalue is '6', then that item gets serviced every 6 months.

Nextduedate is the date the item is due to get serviced next time

I would need to calculate all service dates from Today() upto 12 months after Today(), eg if Today() is 25/10/2018, then I would need to return all service dates upto and including 24/10/2019.

I have a date table, but unsure how to use it in this instance

I can work out the 12 months period, but not sure how to create the service calendar for all items.

Comment: Why is `Frequencyvalue` not an int (or even a tinyint for that matter)? (same question for `Linenum`) What are the possible values of `Frequencytype`?

Comment: They are int in the database, but I have to convert to nvarchar for user understanding when creating reports from them. So I just used nvarchar in the example here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one fairly simple option, using an inline [tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) in the form of a cte and [cross apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-apply):

```
;WITH Tally(n) AS
(
    SELECT TOP 367 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) - 1
    FROM sys.objects
)

SELECT Itemid, Linenum, Engineerid, ServiceDate
FROM #Temp
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT  CASE Frequencytype
            WHEN 'Months' THEN
                DATEADD(MONTH, CAST(Frequencyvalue As Int) * n, Nextduedate)
            WHEN 'Weeks' THEN
                DATEADD(WEEK, CAST(Frequencyvalue As Int) * n, Nextduedate)
            WHEN 'Days' THEN
                DATEADD(DAY, CAST(Frequencyvalue As Int) * n, Nextduedate)
            -- more of the same if needed
            END As ServiceDate
    FROM Tally
) dates
WHERE ServiceDate <= DATEADD(MONTH, 12, GETDATE()) 
-- change getdate() to Nextduedate to get the list for each item up to a year from it's nextduedate
```

Notes:

- The tally table contains numbers between 0 and 366 - based on the assumption that the minimum frequency value is 1 and the minimum frequency type is days.
- The `datepart` argument of the `DateAdd` function can't be parameterized, hence the use of `case`.
- Note that I'm adding `Frequencyvalue` multiplied by `n`
- The `where` clause prevents the cross apply to keep going all the length of the tally table.

Comment: Is it possible to amend this statement to include all ServiceDates upto and including one year from Nextduedate - sometimes the Nextservicedate is actually before today(), eg if I had the below records in the #Temp table:

Comment: Yeah, sure, just change the `Nextduedate` in the `where` clause to `getdate()`. Edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Is it possible to amend this statement to include all ServiceDates upto and including one year from Nextduedate - sometimes the Nextservicedate is actually before today(), eg if I had the below record in the #Temp table:

      ('325302','2','Eng4','06/01/2018','Years','1')

Any way to ensure that for Itemid 325302, linenum 2 - I would get back:

      ItemID    Linenum  Engineerid  Servicedate
      325302  2             Eng4          06/01/2018
      325301  2             Eng4          06/01/2019

Currently I only get back the first line from above

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes - easy - just change the Tally to start at 0. Edited my answer.

Comment: Wait, I think I've got confused here somewhere. Do you want all dates upto and including one year from the day you run the query, or all dates upto and including one year from each row's `Nextduedate`?

Comment: From when the query is run. I think I may have confued you! :)
But its okay, I changed the WHERE clause to:

WHERE ServiceDate <= dateadd(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH, 12, GETDATE()))

This catches the edge cases properly too

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a cursor if you tweek a bit your input (using singular on the frequency), here's what I tested. It's not pretty and cursors are always slow, but it works:

```
create table #Temp
(
  Itemid nvarchar(6), 
  Linenum nVarchar(2), 
  Engineerid nvarchar (4), 
  Nextduedate nvarchar(10), 
  Frequencytype nvarchar (6),
  Frequencyvalue int
)
insert into #Temp 
Values ('325301','1','Eng1','15/11/2018','month',3),
       ('325301','2','Eng2','03/12/2018','month',6),
       ('325302','1','Eng3','04/11/2018','week',7)

declare @finalDate datetime
set  @finalDate = dateadd(month,12,getdate())

declare cCursor cursor for
select Itemid,Linenum,Engineerid,Nextduedate,Frequencytype,Frequencyvalue from #Temp

declare
@Itemid nvarchar(6), 
@Linenum nVarchar(2), 
@Engineerid nvarchar (4), 
@Nextduedate nvarchar(10), 
@Frequencytype nvarchar (6),
@Frequencyvalue int

declare @result table
(
  Itemid nvarchar(6), 
  Linenum nVarchar(2), 
  Engineerid nvarchar (4), 
  serviceDate smalldatetime
)

declare @cmd nvarchar(255), @Parms nvarchar(255), @dt datetime
set @Parms = '@Units int, @dtOutput datetime OUTPUT'

open cCursor 
fetch next from cCursor into @Itemid,@Linenum,@Engineerid,@Nextduedate,@Frequencytype,@Frequencyvalue
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    while 1 = 1
    begin
        set @cmd = 'set @dtOutput = Dateadd(' + @Frequencytype + ',@Units, convert(datetime,''' + @Nextduedate + ''',103))'
        exec sp_ExecuteSQL @cmd, @parms,@Units = @Frequencyvalue, @dtOutput = @dt OUTPUT
        if @finalDate < @dt
            break

        insert into @result select @Itemid,@Linenum,@Engineerid,@dt
        select @Nextduedate = convert(varchar(10), @dt,103)
    end
    fetch next from cCursor into @Itemid,@Linenum,@Engineerid,@Nextduedate,@Frequencytype,@Frequencyvalue
end

close cCursor
deallocate cCursor
drop table #Temp

select * from @result
```

Comment: A cursor is almost never the correct way of doing things in sql, and you probably know it, so why bother posting an answer with a bad (even though working) solution?

Comment: Sorry but I am not allowed to run cursors in the database, thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

@zohar Peled beat me to it. I solved this using my rangeAB function (which is an advanced tally table function).

```
SELECT
  t.Itemid,
  t.Linenum,
  t.Engineerid,
  build.DT
FROM #Temp AS t
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT r.RN, r.N1, DT = 
    CASE t.Frequencytype
      WHEN 'Months' THEN DATEADD(MONTH,r.N1,t.NextDueDate) 
      WHEN 'Weeks'  THEN DATEADD(WEEK, r.N1,t.NextDueDate)
    END
  FROM (VALUES(CASE t.Frequencytype WHEN 'Months' THEN 11 WHEN 'Weeks' THEN 52 END)) AS n(t)
  CROSS APPLY dbo.rangeAB(0,n.t,t.Frequencyvalue,0) AS r
) AS build;
```

Returns:

```
Itemid Linenum Engineerid DT
------ ------- ---------- -----------
325301 1       Eng1       2018-11-15 
325301 1       Eng1       2019-02-15 
325301 1       Eng1       2019-05-15 
325301 1       Eng1       2019-08-15 
325301 2       Eng2       2018-12-03 
325301 2       Eng2       2019-06-03 
325302 1       Eng3       2018-11-04 
325302 1       Eng3       2018-12-23 
325302 1       Eng3       2019-02-10 
325302 1       Eng3       2019-03-31 
325302 1       Eng3       2019-05-19 
325302 1       Eng3       2019-07-07 
325302 1       Eng3       2019-08-25 
325302 1       Eng3       2019-10-13
```

Here's the RangeAB function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.rangeAB
(
  @low  bigint, 
  @high bigint, 
  @gap  bigint,
  @row1 bit
)
/****************************************************************************************
[Purpose]:
 Creates up to 531,441,000,000 sequential integers numbers beginning with @low and ending 
 with @high. Used to replace iterative methods such as loops, cursors and recursive CTEs 
 to solve SQL problems. Based on Itzik Ben-Gan's getnums function with some tweeks and 
 enhancements and added functionality. The logic for getting rn to begin at 0 or 1 is 
 based comes from Jeff Moden's fnTally function. 

 The name range because it's similar to clojure's range function. The name "rangeAB" as 
 used because "range" is a reserved SQL keyword.

[Author]: Alan Burstein

[Compatibility]: 
 SQL Server 2008+ and Azure SQL Database

[Syntax]:
 SELECT r.RN, r.OP, r.N1, r.N2
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(@low,@high,@gap,@row1) AS r;

[Parameters]:
 @low  = a bigint that represents the lowest value for n1.
 @high = a bigint that represents the highest value for n1.
 @gap  = a bigint that represents how much n1 and n2 will increase each row; @gap also
         represents the difference between n1 and n2.
 @row1 = a bit that represents the first value of rn. When @row = 0 then rn begins
         at 0, when @row = 1 then rn will begin at 1.

[Returns]:
 Inline Table Valued Function returns:
 rn = bigint; a row number that works just like T-SQL ROW_NUMBER() except that it can 
      start at 0 or 1 which is dictated by @row1.
 op = bigint; returns the "opposite number that relates to rn. When rn begins with 0 and
      ends with 10 then 10 is the opposite of 0, 9 the opposite of 1, etc. When rn begins
      with 1 and ends with 5 then 1 is the opposite of 5, 2 the opposite of 4, etc...
 n1 = bigint; a sequential number starting at the value of @low and incrimentingby the
      value of @gap until it is less than or equal to the value of @high.
 n2 = bigint; a sequential number starting at the value of @low+@gap and  incrimenting 
      by the value of @gap.

[Dependencies]:
N/A

[Developer Notes]:

 1. The lowest and highest possible numbers returned are whatever is allowable by a 
    bigint. The function, however, returns no more than 531,441,000,000 rows (8100^3). 
 2. @gap does not affect rn, rn will begin at @row1 and increase by 1 until the last row
    unless its used in a query where a filter is applied to rn.
 3. @gap must be greater than 0 or the function will not return any rows.
 4. Keep in mind that when @row1 is 0 then the highest row-number will be the number of
    rows returned minus 1
 5. If you only need is a sequential set beginning at 0 or 1 then, for best performance
    use the RN column. Use N1 and/or N2 when you need to begin your sequence at any 
    number other than 0 or 1 or if you need a gap between your sequence of numbers. 
 6. Although @gap is a bigint it must be a positive integer or the function will
    not return any rows.
 7. The function will not return any rows when one of the following conditions are true:
      * any of the input parameters are NULL
      * @high is less than @low 
      * @gap is not greater than 0
    To force the function to return all NULLs instead of not returning anything you can
    add the following code to the end of the query:

      UNION ALL 
      SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
      WHERE NOT (@high&@low&@gap&@row1 IS NOT NULL AND @high >= @low AND @gap > 0)

    This code was excluded as it adds a ~5% performance penalty.
 8. There is no performance penalty for sorting by rn ASC; there is a large performance 
    penalty for sorting in descending order WHEN @row1 = 1; WHEN @row1 = 0
    If you need a descending sort the use op in place of rn then sort by rn ASC. 

Best Practices:
--===== 1. Using RN (rownumber)
 -- (1.1) The best way to get the numbers 1,2,3...@high (e.g. 1 to 5):
 SELECT RN FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,5,1,1);
 -- (1.2) The best way to get the numbers 0,1,2...@high-1 (e.g. 0 to 5):
 SELECT RN FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,5,1,0);

--===== 2. Using OP for descending sorts without a performance penalty
 -- (2.1) The best way to get the numbers 5,4,3...@high (e.g. 5 to 1):
 SELECT op FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,5,1,1) ORDER BY rn ASC;
 -- (2.2) The best way to get the numbers 0,1,2...@high-1 (e.g. 5 to 0):
 SELECT op FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,6,1,0) ORDER BY rn ASC;

--===== 3. Using N1
 -- (3.1) To begin with numbers other than 0 or 1 use N1 (e.g. -3 to 3):
 SELECT N1 FROM dbo.rangeAB(-3,3,1,1);
 -- (3.2) ROW_NUMBER() is built in. If you want a ROW_NUMBER() include RN:
 SELECT RN, N1 FROM dbo.rangeAB(-3,3,1,1);
 -- (3.3) If you wanted a ROW_NUMBER() that started at 0 you would do this:
 SELECT RN, N1 FROM dbo.rangeAB(-3,3,1,0);

--===== 4. Using N2 and @gap
 -- (4.1) To get 0,10,20,30...100, set @low to 0, @high to 100 and @gap to 10:
 SELECT N1 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,100,10,1);
 -- (4.2) Note that N2=N1+@gap; this allows you to create a sequence of ranges.
 --       For example, to get (0,10),(10,20),(20,30).... (90,100):
 SELECT N1, N2 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,90,10,1);
 -- (4.3) Remember that a rownumber is included and it can begin at 0 or 1:
 SELECT RN, N1, N2 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,90,10,1);

[Examples]:
--===== 1. Generating Sample data (using rangeAB to create "dummy rows")
 -- The query below will generate 10,000 ids and random numbers between 50,000 and 500,000
 SELECT
   someId    = r.rn,
   someNumer = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%450000)+50001 
 FROM rangeAB(1,10000,1,1) r;

--===== 2. Create a series of dates; rn is 0 to include the first date in the series
 DECLARE @startdate DATE = '20180101', @enddate DATE = '20180131';

 SELECT r.rn, calDate = DATEADD(dd, r.rn, @startdate)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(1, DATEDIFF(dd,@startdate,@enddate),1,0) r;
 GO

--===== 3. Splitting (tokenizing) a string with fixed sized items
 -- given a delimited string of identifiers that are always 7 characters long
 DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'A601225,B435223,G008081,R678567';

 SELECT
   itemNumber = r.rn, -- item's ordinal position 
   itemIndex  = r.n1, -- item's position in the string (it's CHARINDEX value)
   item       = SUBSTRING(@string, r.n1, 7) -- item (token)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(1, LEN(@string), 8,1)  r;
 GO

--===== 4. Splitting (tokenizing) a string with random delimiters
 DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'ABC123,999F,XX,9994443335';

 SELECT
   itemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY r.rn), -- item's ordinal position 
   itemIndex  = r.n1+1, -- item's position in the string (it's CHARINDEX value)
   item       = SUBSTRING
               (
                 @string,
                 r.n1+1,
                 ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',',@string,r.n1+1),0)-r.n1-1, 8000)
               ) -- item (token)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,DATALENGTH(@string),1,1) r
 WHERE SUBSTRING(@string,r.n1,1) = ',' OR r.n1 = 0;
 -- logic borrowed from: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

--===== 5. Grouping by a weekly intervals
 -- 5.1. how to create a series of start/end dates between @startDate & @endDate
 DECLARE @startDate DATE = '1/1/2015', @endDate DATE = '2/1/2015';
 SELECT 
   WeekNbr   = r.RN,
   WeekStart = DATEADD(DAY,r.N1,@StartDate), 
   WeekEnd   = DATEADD(DAY,r.N2-1,@StartDate)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,datediff(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate),7,1) r;
 GO

 -- 5.2. LEFT JOIN to the weekly interval table
 BEGIN
  DECLARE @startDate datetime = '1/1/2015', @endDate datetime = '2/1/2015';
  -- sample data 
  DECLARE @loans TABLE (loID INT, lockDate DATE);
  INSERT @loans SELECT r.rn, DATEADD(dd, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%32), @startDate)
  FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,50,1,1) r;

  -- solution 
  SELECT 
    WeekNbr   = r.RN,
    WeekStart = dt.WeekStart, 
    WeekEnd   = dt.WeekEnd,
    total     = COUNT(l.lockDate)
  FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,datediff(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate),7,1) r
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY,r.N1,@StartDate) AS DATE), 
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY,r.N2-1,@StartDate) AS DATE))) dt(WeekStart,WeekEnd)
  LEFT JOIN @loans l ON l.lockDate BETWEEN  dt.WeekStart AND dt.WeekEnd
  GROUP BY r.RN, dt.WeekStart, dt.WeekEnd ;
 END;

--===== 6. Identify the first vowel and last vowel in a along with their positions
 DECLARE @string VARCHAR(200) = 'This string has vowels';

 SELECT TOP(1) position = r.rn, letter = SUBSTRING(@string,r.rn,1)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,LEN(@string),1,1) r
 WHERE SUBSTRING(@string,r.rn,1) LIKE '%[aeiou]%'
 ORDER BY r.rn;

 -- To avoid a sort in the execution plan we'll use op instead of rn
 SELECT TOP(1) position = r.op, letter = SUBSTRING(@string,r.op,1)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,LEN(@string),1,1) r
 WHERE SUBSTRING(@string,r.rn,1) LIKE '%[aeiou]%'
 ORDER BY r.rn;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Revision History]:
 Rev 00 - 20140518 - Initial Development - Alan Burstein
 Rev 01 - 20151029 - Added 65 rows to make L1=465; 465^3=100.5M. Updated comment section
                   - Alan Burstein
 Rev 02 - 20180613 - Complete re-design including opposite number column (op)
 Rev 03 - 20180920 - Added additional CROSS JOIN to L2 for 530B rows max - Alan Burstein
****************************************************************************************/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
WITH L1(N) AS 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM (VALUES
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0)) T(N) -- 90 values 
),
L2(N)  AS (SELECT 1 FROM L1 a CROSS JOIN L1 b CROSS JOIN L1 c),
iTally AS (SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM L2 a CROSS JOIN L2 b)
SELECT  
  r.RN,
  r.OP,
  r.N1,
  r.N2
FROM
(
  SELECT
    RN = 0,
    OP = (@high-@low)/@gap,
    N1 = @low,
    N2 = @gap+@low
  WHERE @row1 = 0
  UNION ALL -- COALESCE required in the TOP statement below for error handling purposes
  SELECT TOP (ABS((COALESCE(@high,0)-COALESCE(@low,0))/COALESCE(@gap,0)+COALESCE(@row1,1)))
    RN = i.rn,
    OP = (@high-@low)/@gap+(2*@row1)-i.rn,
    N1 = (i.rn-@row1)*@gap+@low,
    N2 = (i.rn-(@row1-1))*@gap+@low
  FROM iTally AS i
  ORDER BY rn
) AS r
WHERE @high&@low&@gap&@row1 IS NOT NULL AND @high >= @low AND @gap > 0;
```

Comment: This is starting to be a habit :-) You know you can simply post that function in some blog...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply but I cannot create functions into the database. Many thanks for the reply!